# How can i did same onscreen notification?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I want to do same notification as Any.do on bottom of screen like this [image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4bo0ggnpr6zk8r/Screenshot_2015-09-22-22-45-57.jpg?dl=0]

How can I do it? What is it? What I need to look for?

Comment: change your wall paper & then post qtn later

Answer (score 0):

You can try to display a layout dynamically and fix it on the bottom of your screen, as a footer. In this specific case, you can use a combinaison of `LinearLayour` or a `GridLayout`.

If you want to know how to fix a layout on the bottom of the screen, you can follow this example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-header-and-footer-layout-example.html

If you don't need to let the user interact with your notification, you can use a custom `Toast`